# [UICollectionView performSelector:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having problem with my iOS app which I am not sure what is the root cause of it even after I've turned on NSZombie to debug.

Already tried to google with reliable source but still couldn't get any answer.

For my iOS App, I am using MMDrawerController Library as the left slide menu. Which I am having a problem when I switching view from left menu, if the page contains UICollectionView, it will crash with the message below.

```
[UICollectionView performSelector:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

The view load smooth for the first time, but when I attempt to switch back from another view, it crashed with the error above.

Here are my UICollectionView Data Source and cell builder functions

```
#pragma mark: UICollectionViewCell Builder
- (ItemNormalCVCell *)buildItemNormalCVCell:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ItemNormalCVCell *cell      = [self.mCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CVCellItemNormal" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

- (LoadingCVCell *)buildLoadingCVCell:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    LoadingCVCell *cell   = [self.mCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CVCellLoading" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark: UICollectionView DataSource
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSInteger itemsCount    = self.items.count;

    if( self.isLoading_.boolValue )
        return itemsCount + 1;

    return itemsCount;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger itemsCount    = self.items.count;

    if( self.isLoading_.boolValue ){

        if( indexPath.row == itemsCount )
            return [self buildLoadingCVCell:indexPath];
    }

    return [self buildItemNormalCVCell:indexPath];
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat cvWidth     = (self.view.frame.size.width / 2) - 1.f;

    return CGSizeMake(cvWidth, 300.f);
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 1.f); // top, left, bottom, right
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return 1.f;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return 1.f;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to call the method directly? Consensus says performSelector: [isn't always safe](http://www.tomdalling.com/blog/cocoa/why-performselector-is-more-dangerous-than-i-thought/) with ARC.

Comment: Hi @Dare, thanks for the comment. May I know what do you mean by call the method directly? I just edited the question with my codes attached. Not sure if it helps

Comment: Ah, OK, that makes sense. The controller was probably deallocated when it went off screen. Does the debugger give you a method signature when it crashes?

Comment: @Dare, not it doesn't. It only return the line [UICollectionView performSelector:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance when it crashes. I suspecting is because the data source somehow is missing when the view load. But I've tried to programatically put in self.collectionView.dataSource = (id)self. But unfortunately still not working.